# No overload matches this call on angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i dont really quite understand what the router.event.subscribe does, im following a tutorial from here
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/154/Angular-6-Tutorial---Learn-Angular-6-in-this-Crash-Course
but i got and error on this part '((_: NavigationEnd) => this.currentUrl = _.url) ', can someone please help me fix this? and while on that please elaborate what this line does. thank you so much.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  currentUrl: any;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((_: NavigationEnd) => this.currentUrl = _.url);
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Comment: Can you add what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Routers have different life cycle phase to follow up. When a router initialise or complete its one cycle its updates via this event subscription.

Here is the list:

`NavigationStart`: Navigation starts.

`RouteConfigLoadStart`: Before the router lazy loads a route configuration.

`RouteConfigLoadEnd`: After a route has been lazy loaded.

`RoutesRecognized`: When the router parses the URL and the routes are recognized.

`GuardsCheckStart`: When the router begins the guards phase of routing.

`ChildActivationStart`: When the router begins activating a route's children.

`ActivationStart`: When the router begins activating a route.

`GuardsCheckEnd`: When the router finishes the guards phase of routing successfully.

`ResolveStart`: When the router begins the resolve phase of routing.

`ResolveEnd`: When the router finishes the resolve phase of routing successfuly.

`ChildActivationEnd`: When the router finishes activating a route's children.

`ActivationEnd`: When the router finishes activating a route.

`NavigationEnd`: When navigation ends successfully.

`NavigationCancel`: When navigation is canceled.

`NavigationError`: When navigation fails due to an unexpected error.

`Scroll`: When the user scrolls.

Check for more details [here](https://angular.io/api/router/Event).